# How to define "time" parameter of glsl on android

Tags: android, time, opengl-es

I'm studying glsl of OpenGL ES on android and trying to run [this code](http://glslsandbox.com/e#24303.0) on my android device. However, I don't know how to defined `time` parameter. When I passed the `time` parameter as follows,

```
int time = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "time");
GLES20.glUniform1f(time, System.currentTimeMillis());
```

I couldn't see any motion of the gradational image on screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use,

```
GLES20.glUniform1f(time, (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000) % 60);
```

modify time value in [this code](http://glslsandbox.com/e#24303.0). If set time value is `1513913007000` and add the value by `1000` or `2000`, any motion will not be see. This is due to `Subexpression` with time too large than other, and real time flow too little for `System.currentTimeMillis()`

Comment: Thanks. But, when I use your code, it doesn't move smoothly. It's like slideshow of several fixed shots.

Comment: `(System.currentTimeMillis() / m) % n) / (float)t`. if you want more quick, can set `m` more small. Or, don't use `System.currentTimeMillis()`, use `auto-increment` value instead of. If you want more smoothly, set `m` small and set `n` big and select suitable `t`.  there's a lot more expression, and this one is certainly not best.

Comment: Finally, I found proper code, thanks to your idea. This is my code `GLES20.glUniform1f(time, ((System.currentTimeMillis() - mStartTime) / 1000.0f));`. mStartTime is the time when my app started. Thanks.

Comment: @THKay.  The change of `((System.currentTimeMillis() - mStartTime) / 1000.0f));`  will be more and more slower. There are 86400 seconds in one day. If the program don't continuously run, it don't matter.